# Select specific table model element on a filtered JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, rowfilter

On a JTable, I can select a specific row by using `table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowIndex, rowIndex)`.

Now what I would like to do is the following:

1. I open the frame containing the JTable and pass a specific table model element to it
2. The matching table row gets highlighted/selected

I already made a method inside my tableModel called `getElementRowIndex` that returns the model index of the element I'm passing on to it. But now I can't select that row because the table is filtered using a RowFilter and so many of my RowIndexes are off or out of bounds.

I can get the current model index for a selected row by using `table.convertRowIndexToModel`. But what I need is something like `table.convertModelIndexToRow`. Is there such a thing? How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the inverse method is

```
 table.convertRowIndexToView(modelIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you. I somehow overlooked that method.